# Services Design and Authentication/Authorization across services

Tags: web-services, api, rest, soa

I'm working on developing my first SOA web-based application. I'm extremely new to SOA and still trying to wrap my head around best design principles for service design, especially in the way that services should talk to another.

The current problem I'm trying to figure out has to do with authentication and authorization. Lets say I have a trivial user service and event service, where the event service represents events in a calendar. Is it general practice to have the event service call the user service to authorize the request? Or, would it be better practice to implement user authorization on a system that exists between the client and the requested service? The system, which is essentially just another service, checks to user credentials to make sure they have access to the requested action (GET events/1, etc) and if so, sends the request to the service. This service could also act as a central load balancer and cache...I just like the idea of keeping user logic outside of each specific service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use siteminder as authentication and authorization. Only the client who has valid token can invoke the service. you could also have roles assigned in siteminder.